# How to set Android Push notifications with custom sound on the server with firebase cloud messaging?

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I am trying to get a custom sound in android when receiving a notification when the app is in the background.

Here is my code I have tried but is not working. What am I doing wrong???

```
const message: admin.messaging.Message = {
    data: {
        type: "message",
        Id: Id
    },
    notification: {
        body: "Body",
        title: "title"
    },
    android: {
        ttl: 60000,
        priority: "high",
        notification: {
            body: "Android test body",
            title: "Android test title",
            sound: "test.wav"
        }
    },
    apns: {
        headers: {
            "apns-priority": "10",
            "apns-expiration": "" + (Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60)
        },
        payload: {
            aps: {
                sound: "OnceAgainNotification.caf"
            }
        }
    },
    token: token
};
```